# Prevent input-group from spanning full width of Bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Twitter-Bootstrap nav bar which includes a Search form

The problem I'm having is that the search bar spans the full width of the nag bar when I use an input-group

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ce3SS/

and here's my code...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Brand name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse" id="header-nav">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="inputSearch">Search...</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSearch" name="inputSearch" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>                
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can get the search to be a more sensible size and over to the right without having to hack the CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="header-nav">
      <form class="navbar-form">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/107803

Answer (score 1):

You can play adding `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4` classes in the `div.input-group` to preserve responsive features.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a simple fix. You just want to use CSS to apply a width to the input field. Then, you can move it around. Try adding the style on the markup itself.

```
<div class="input-group" style="width: 20%">
```

(I made it 20%, but you can add whatever).

I always use % with bootstrap, so that my changed don't negatively affect it's responsiveness.

Edit: Fixed which tag I was styling

Comment: Percentage is not good because it does affect responsiveness.. especially when changing media sizes and the entire layout changes. Imagine 20% width on a small 4" device.. that should be 100% -  I do not think this is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap V4 (Feb 2019), the proper way to do this is to use `w-auto`.

On the smallest screen size, `.input-group`, has a width of 100%, on all other screen sizes the width is auto.

```
<div class="input-group w-auto">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Really straight forward!